# linux: munmap shared memory in on single call

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap

If a process calls `mmap(...,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED,...)` and forks N children, is it possible for any one of these processes (parent or descendants) to `munmap()` the memory for all processes in one go, thus releasing the physical memory, or does every of these processes have to munmap() individually?
(I know the memory will be unmapped on process exit, but the children won't exit yet).

Alternatively, is there a way to munmap memory from another process?  I'm thinking of a call something like `munmap(pid,...)`.

Or is there a way to achieve what I am looking for using non-anonymous mappings and performing an operation on the related file descriptor (e.g closing the file)?

My processes are performance sensitive, and I would like to avoid performing lots of IPC when it becomes known that the shared memory will no longer be used by anyone.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to `unmap` mappings of other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there is no way to unmap memory in one go.
2. If you don't need mapped memory in child processes at all, you may mark mappings with `madvise(MADV_DONTFORK)` before forking.
3. In emergency situations, you may invoke syscalls from inside external processes by using gdb:

   1. Figure out PID of target process
   2. List mapped memory with `cat /proc/<PID>/maps`
   3. Attach to process using gdb: `gdb -p <PID>` (it will suspend execution of target process)
   4. Run from gdb: `call munmap(0x<address>, 0x<size>)` for each region you need to unmap
   5. Exit gdb (execution of process is resumed)

   It must be obvious that if your process tries to access unmapped memory, it will receive SIGSEGV. So, you must be 100% sure what you are doing.

Comment: 1) I guess this is the answer. not the one I wished, but the answer. 2)In my case the processes do use the memory for a while. Otherwise I would not share it to start with. 3) not relevant here. This was not a debugging question. Thanks for the info anyway

Comment: If `gdb` can invoke `munmap` using the `ptrace()` interface, then you can write a program to do it - debuggers aren't specially privileged.  It probably won't be trivial though, as you'll need to reimplement much of GDB's code...